# link_to_remote and link_to in Rails 3

Tags: ruby, link-to

I'm a newbie spanish Rails developer. ¿Can u help me with a problem with Rails?

I have an application with RoR 2 and Google maps and i catch X and Y coord
to send to a controller. I use :with parameter

:catastro,:url =>
{:controller => "instalacions", :action => "catastro_ajax" }, :with=>"'coordx='+$('instalacion_longitud').value+'&coordy='+$('instalacion_latitud').value" %>

In the method :with i pass values from input text using prototype, but in Rails 3 the instruction link_to haven't :with method and i don´t know how to pass values from input text to a controller.

How can i migrate this instruction to Rails 3? I only need know how to
capture the input text values to send to the controller.

Thanks!!

PS: Sorry for my english!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to stop using obtrusive javascript. To get a grasp of the concept and how to implement it, take a look at this railscast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/205-unobtrusive-javascript